# My Android app is freezing when I call bufferedReader.readLine();

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, wear-os, channel-api

I created a new Android Studio project for an Android phone and an Android Wear to test the [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi). It seems that everything works fine in my project, except that inside the `onChannelOpened` method I cannot read from `InputStream` without freezing the app.

This is how I send the message from the Wearable (which seems to work):

```
Wearable.ChannelApi.openChannel(googleApiClient, node.getId(), channelIdentifier).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ChannelApi.OpenChannelResult openChannelResult) {
        final Channel channel = openChannelResult.getChannel();
        channel.getOutputStream(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Channel.GetOutputStreamResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Channel.GetOutputStreamResult getOutputStreamResult) {
        final String message = "hello from your smartwatch";
        try {
            getOutputStreamResult.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());
            Log.d(TAG, "sendMessageToNode: onResult: onResult: Message sent: " + message);
        }
        // ...
```

The log prints: `D/MainActivity﹕ sendMessageToNode: onResult: onResult: Message sent: hello from your smartwatch`

On the smartphone side I try to read the message as follows:

```
@Override
public void onChannelOpened(final Channel channel) {
    channel.getInputStream(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Channel.GetInputStreamResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Channel.GetInputStreamResult getInputStreamResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChannelOpened: onResult");

            String message = "";
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getInputStreamResult.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = "";
                //while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                while (true) {
                    // Next line is freezing the app
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChannelOpened: onResult: line: " + line);
                    message += line + "\n";
                    if (line == null) break;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onChannelOpened: onResult: Received the following message: \" + message");
                // ...
```

The log prints: `D/MainActivity﹕ onChannelOpened: onResult` but that's it.

I started the debugger and now know that the error must be in this line: `line = bufferedReader.readLine();`. But there is no exception thrown or anything else. The debugger even shows me that the buffer has the right values:

[image: Debugger shows right values]

I am trying to send "hello from your smartwatch". However, the app seems to freeze. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried running this code asynchronously in another thread (`AsyncTask`)?

Comment: @KristianVukusic Thanks for your help. The given String is not very long and with further testing I figured out that the ``bufferedReader.readLine();`` method never returns ``null``. Furthermore the ``inputStream.read()``method never returns ``-1`` and doesn't throw an exception. This is some strange behavior I cannot explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to close the stream on the sender side otherwise the receiver wouldn't know if more data would be coming down through the channel or not.

Comment: You are right! I forgot to close the ``OutputStream`` and therefore I didn't receive ``null`` or ``-1``at the end of the stream (because there was no end). Thanks a lot! After 10 hours of work the concentration sinks too deep I guess. But next time something like this happens I will find the solution much faster :-)